# ¿ Que es la compilacion?

Tags: compilar, compilacion

Soy algo nuevo en el mundo de la programación y he escuchado a varios programadores amigos diciendo que su código no compila, que se demora mucho y aún no entiendo . Busqué en Google y más o menos leí que el compilador lo que hace es como transformar el código de un lenguaje en otro, realmente no sé si esta informacion esté bien o mal, desearía que alguien me explicara en qué se basa la compilación, para que sirve, que me den algun conocimiento algo profundo respecto a la compilación.

Comment: Compilar significa traducir lo que escribe a algo que pueda ser ejecutado por el computador.

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta porque no es una consulta de programación

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dices:

> el compilador lo que hace es como transformar el código de un lenguaje en otro

Si pero a lenguaje máquina. Sin embargo los lenguajes como Java y los lenguajes .NET de Microsoft se traducen en un código intermedio que es independiente de la máquina.

En efecto la compilación significa tomar un programa desarrollado en un lenguaje de programación x el cual es un formato que los programadores pueden leer y mantener, y convertirlo en un formato que pueda ejecutar la computadora (o sistema operativo).


Por ejemplo, hoy cuando escribes una aplicación de Android, generalmente escribes en Java. Luego llama a javac el cual es el compilador de java para compilarlo en código de bytes Java, que es un lenguaje binario que JVM (Java Virtual Machine) interpreta y ejecuta.


También hay compiladores de código fuente a fuente, por ejemplo el primer compilador de C ++ (cfront) tradujo la fuente de C ++ a la fuente de C para su posterior compilación por parte del compilador de C existente. De esta manera, el compilador de C ++ era independiente de la máquina y podía generar directamente código de máquina para cualquier computadora que tuviera un compilador de C.


Por lo tanto un compilador es un programa de software que convierte el código de programación de computadoras escrito por un programador humano en código binario (código de máquina) que puede ser entendido y ejecutado por una CPU específica. **El acto de transformar el código fuente en código de máquina se llama "compilación".** Cuando todo el código se transforma a la vez antes de que llegue a las plataformas que lo ejecutan, el proceso se denomina compilación anticipada (AOT).


Fuentes:

- https://www.thoughtco.com/definition-of-compiler-958198
- https://lambda.uta.edu/cse5317/notes/node3.html
- https://www.quora.com/What-does-it-mean-to-compile-a-computer-program

Answer (score 2):

Cuando tu compilas tu código, lo que estás haciendo es pedirle al compilador que te traduzca el archivo escrito en lenguaje de programación (extensión `.java` por ejemplo), a un código que la máquina sea capaz de leer (en el caso de Java te genera un archivo `.class`, ese archivo será el que el interprete, que es la Java Virtual Machine) va a leer para ejecutar el programa.

Espero haberte puesto algo de luz en el asunto.

Comment: Hola @Persona.ferran ! Gracias por tu ayuda, pero esto no provee una respuesta clara a la pregunta, cuando tengas reputación suficiente podrás comentar las preguntas, el espacio de respuesta es para dar una respuesta clara, concisa y detallada al problema del autor.